# sqlite3 encryption on c++ visual studio project with sqlite_has_codec 64 bits

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sqlite, openssl, mingw

i am trying to compile a project using sqlite3.c and a wrapper in c++ CppSqlite3.cpp. It is compiling by pure magic in 32 bits but not 64.

In my c/c++ compiler, i am including this :

```
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin; 
C:\MinGW\bin;
C:\OpenSSL-Win32\openssl-1.0.2e\include; 
C:\JDK\include;
C:\JDK\include\win32;
```

In my linker i am including this :

```
C:\Haylem\Devtools\Compiler\OpenSSL\lib
```

and using this lib :

```
libeay32.dll.a
```

All this works in 32 bits by miracle but in 64 bits i got 22 unresolved external symbols for example this one :

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _EVP_CIPHER_key_length   xxxx_project_xxxx sqlite3.obj   1

I know it is something to do with openssl, libcrypt something but i guess x64 need another lib for that? where can i find this? thanks

Comment: Post a [mcve] please. Your post does not have enough information to answer the question.

Comment: Learn how it works please before downvoting. You have all the info in the world or ask for more. Don't downvote when you have no idea how to help.

Comment: I downvoted this purely because it is a horribly incomplete question.

Comment: You don't need code or anything else, it is a linker error on a specific library. I didn't know which lib i needed for openSSL and the errors weren't clear for me. Guess you are just part of a group that only check the structure of a question and downvote people. I see a lot of you guys on stackoverflow.

Comment: sure, that all I do. I've never actually answered someones question. Just keep believing that - it's not like I care one way or the other, random person on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, if someone get those unresolved external symbols one day. It is a linker error with the openSSL library. You need libeay32.lib for 64 bit even if it says libeay**32**.lib there is a 32 and x64 version out there on the web precompiled for you.